# Program Outputs Strange, Random Values When Run

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a programming task and when I print the values that my function "explode" finds, it is outputting some strange values that are not even stored in my vector, such as "80" and "112". Can anybody please help find why it is outputting the values 80 and 112 when they are not in my vector?

**Input**

6

8

5

6

13

3

4

I have tested to see the contents of my vector and they do not contain these strange values that my program outputs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
typedef long long ll;
using namespace std;

ll N, ans=0, cnt=1;
vector<ll> a;

void explode(ll ind, ll rad, ll dir)
{
  if (dir==1 && ind!=N-1)
  {
    ll i = ind+1, explode_count=0;
    while (a[i]<=a[ind]+rad) {cnt++; cout << a[i] << "\n"; i++; explode_count++;}
    if (explode_count>=1) explode(i-1, rad+1, 1);
  }
  else if (dir==-1 && ind!=0)
  {
    ll i = ind-1, explode_count=0;
    while (a[i]>=a[ind]-rad) {cnt++; cout << a[i] << "\n"; i--; explode_count++;}
    if (explode_count>=1) explode(i+1, rad+1, -1);
  }
}

int main()
{
  ofstream fout("angry.out");
  ifstream fin("angry.in");
  fin >> N;
  for (ll i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    ll c;
    fin >> c;
    a.push_back(c);
  }
  sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  for (ll i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    explode(i,1,1);
    explode(i,1,-1);
    ans=max(ans, cnt);
    cnt=1;
  }
  fout << ans << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably accessing the vector out of bounds. Try using a debugger and replace `a[x]` calls with `a.at(x)`, which does bounds checking and will throw an exception if you access out of bounds.

Comment: There's certainly a complete lack of bounds checking here, and the most likely explanation is an out of bounds vector access resulting in undefined behavior. Recheck your algorithm, and implement proper bounds checking.

Comment: You problem is that at one point in `while (a[i]>=a[ind]-rad) {cnt++; cout << a[i] << "\n"; i--; explode_count++;}` i becomes 0 and the the `i--` decrements it to -1 which is not valid.